# Any Ideas for Extracting the lines on a Football Pitch?

Tags: image-processing

Ok, so my goal is to extract the pitch bounding lines (not the vertical ones down the center or the semicircle) from an image such as:

[source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9g5h.jpg)

With the goal of speed, id like to avoid an ML approach, and focus on image processing.

So far, i've been using morphological operations to attempt to achieve my result, the algorithm is as follows:

-> [greyscale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83Rra.jpg)

-> [canny algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BEDM.jpg)

-> [morphological close (square 3x3 structuring element )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnSzm.jpg)

-> [morphological open (line 1 x 10 structuring element)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmZuL.jpg)

-> [morphological dilate x4 (line 1 x 30 structuring element)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPIO8.jpg)

I then find the contours of the resulting image, fit a line to each set of contours, and chose the two lines of greatest length to be the pitch lines, and generate a mask accordingly to isolate the pitch.

For this example the results are pretty good : [RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sj1H1.jpg)

But the problem is that it works fairly inconsistently, e.g for the other example image I linked above, here is the [RESULT + FINAL IMAGE BEFORE FINDING CONTOURS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YABbB.jpg) ... completely misses the pitch. I *can* alter a few parameters to get it to work for this image, but I'm looking for a solution which can work consistently such that it can be used to process a video, extracting only the pitch each frame.

I think the biggest problem is the crow, lots of noise, lines and colours, leading to miss-classifications or objects as pitch lines.

If anyone has any ideas for a way to consistently detect these pitch lines (morphologically or otherwise) i'd love to hear it.

Comment: Have you looked at spectral analysis, usually 2D, then filter, or maybe even 1D along the scan lines? As a pre-preprocess you could mix your own colour channels (pseudo-monochrome) in stead of greyscale. Reverse transform and then proceed with close/dilate etc.. to crisp along line centers. Nice project!

Comment: The 2-d white lines existing in a 3-d world are known, right? You just want to fit camera 6 DoF to that object (assuming no camera distortion, no occlusion etc). You can probably restrict it to a finite volume of possible camera locations.

Comment: @KnutInge even with occlusion/obstruction, and unknown camera location, your suggestion to ultimately fit (distort) a known pattern to the image, rather than draw the pattern from the image, is likely the best approach using the most available information. Of course, he still has to find what in the image to match it to.

Comment: @Knut Inge , let me get this right, are you guys suggesting that I should restrict the camera to 6 possible locations, and then obtain an affine transform for each one which makes it seem as though the camera is centered, and then proceed from there?

Comment: @P2000 how about canny algorithm to obtain the pitch lines -> morph close (as before) -> then using the result as a mask, mask the source image and take the 2d fourier transform, then try to filter out the non-white frequencies? Don't have a tonne of experience with spectral analysis.

Comment: Do you know the location of the cameras? In any case, I think there are 2 steps 1) extract lines (or sections, scratches ...) using morphology (& maybe spectral analysis), then 2) try to distort/transform a reference pitch to match up with those lines, accounting for angle, distortion, obstructions.... If the camera location is known, your fitting will be easier and faster.

Comment: I dont precisely know the camera position, but I have a video where the camera pans the length of the pitch a few times, so I assume it can be estimated. Once stage 1 has been completed and a set of possible pitch lines has been extracted, are you suggesting trying to fit a reference pitch to each line and choosing the ones which give the most appropriate fit?

Comment: My thought was that you know the object: a rectangle with a circle and two semi circles. If the camera can move in x y z and rotate in x y z vs that object, you have a 6-dimensional search in order to find the most likely field?

Comment: @KnutInge a good thought, thank you. might be challenging to implement however.